# Showing users even they not involved

Tags: support

In the home page, you can see the user `Community` is shown. But when opening the question, there is no involvment of community at all

Question link : [Captive Portal detection causing phones to disconnect from Wi-Fi in intranet environment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139588/captive-portal-detection-causing-phones-to-disconnect-from-wi-fi-in-intranet-env)

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Image : (the second question; click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

"Community" is not a real user. Several actions that are taken automatically by the system are shown as being done by the "Community" user, including this action of occasionally touching old questions to put them on the homepage.

Answer (score 3):

Take a closer look:

> [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Izzy, flags like this one don't appear on mobile. Something *else* to go and winge about to the Devs, as primarily-mobile users like myself have no idea what is going on when flags start being set.

Comment: @DanBrown It seems that there's no real interest in updating the Android SE app, though.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I know. Shame, isn't it?

Comment: @DanBrown Quite. Were it open source, most of these problems could've already been addressed.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Yeah, true.  Who knows, maybe we could ask nicely for that? ;)

Comment: @DanBrown We could, but there's no telling whether the developer actually reads the mail.

Comment: @Hmmm, true. I'll see what I can dig up in a bit, though this is for the mobile site, not the app. Is it the same issue there then?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman ^ (I wonder if anyone here is called Hmmm)

Comment: Hmmm might be interested in knowing that this issue occurs in the app as well. #D